# Does pystan/stan still have a module for misc? Function for stan_rdump?

Tags: pystan

When I import pystan I get this error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystan'**.
From another forum thread, I now `import stan` (instead of pystan).

However, the problem happens when I use `stan.misc.stan_rdump`. The error is: **AttributeError: module 'stan' has no attribute 'misc'**.

Please advise. Thanks.